# Django models: how to avoid cascade deletes

Tags: django, django-models

I have a general question about designing Django models and considering the effect that has on a cascade delete.  Suppose the following simple design of an Asset Management app.

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    aquire_date = models.DateField()
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)

class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    email = models.EmailField()

class Account(models.Model):
    account_number = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Department(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

So each Asset has 3 ForeignKey fields to other tables.  Reading the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects) it says 'any objects which had foreign keys pointing at the object to be deleted will be deleted along with it'.  I read that to mean if I delete a Department object, the Asset object, or objects, the ForeignKey is referring to will be deleted as well.  But if I delete an Asset, the Department, Vendor, and Account remains.

Is that the correct way to understand cascade deletes in Django?

What I would prefer is

- when an Asset is deleted, no department, vendor, or account is deleted;
- when a Department is deleted, no Asset is deleted, but all ForeignKey fields that point to that Department are set to null.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

Solution: When [creating a model `ForeignKey` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey), supply `on_delete=django.db.models.SET_NULL`. You need to combine this with `null=True` to allow this because the default is `False`.

Comment: Phil, thank you for the answer!  That worked!  I think you wrote the answer faster than it took me to create the question.  Sometimes you know what you want to do, it's just hard to find it in the Django documentation.